# Change all Color on Text Controller

Tags: android, android-studio

I need change all color for EditText, I tried all my information

ex:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:state_window_focused="false"
        android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

    <item
        android:drawable="@color/colorJust" />

</selector>
```

with: `android:background="@drawable/edittext_bg"`

[image]

But result is not good, the pink color is always on top when click and select text

I need to remove this PINK color i hate it!

[image]

Comment: what you want? remove this blinking pink cursor or change its color?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The colour of the checkboxes, cursor, etc. is determined by your accent [see here](https://developer.android.com/training/material/theme.html)

Try adding this to your styles:

```
<item name="android:colorAccent">@color/colorJust</item>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is my first application =)

Answer (score 0):

you can choose `android:textCursorDrawable="@null"`, the cursor will use `android:textColor` color then. or to remove cursor from edittext you can do something like `android:cursorVisible="false"`